# CORS headers are not exposed in react/axios even if the headers are listed in Access-Control-Expose-Headers in response from server

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors

I have a react app which uses **Axios** for requesting server. My server is a grails app.
I want to read all response headers in my client site react code. For this in my grails app, i have set to expose all the headers i need and they are showing in browser and also listed in **Access-Control-Expose-Headers**. But still i am not able to access the header in my code.
In my axios code, i am using axios interceptor to read the response like :

```
api.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    console.log("response",response)
    let reqObject = response.request
    console.log("type", typeof reqObject)
    let resHeaders = reqObject.getResponseHeader('prabin');
    console.log("resHeaders",resHeaders)
    return response;
},function(error){
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

This is giving error in browser console for chrome as :
***Refused to get unsafe header "prabin"***

I am not understanding what i am missing. [image: header prabin is listed in Access-Control-Expose-Headers]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong with my implementation. These headers in
**`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`**:

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp
```

It seems they are invalid because of which client javascript code couldn't read the required headers.
After removal of these headers, i am able to read the exposed headers in client code.

Answer (score -1):

Server needs to give access to your origin. If you see headers in network it doesn't mean that all of this headers you will see in code. Check what you have on server